# SQL error when using two tables in Android

Tags: android, mysql, syntax-error

I'm trying to get orders sorted by the customers delivery order.
This SQL statement works in my desktop database, but when I run it on the Android I get an error.

I tried using `_id` as well.

> near "c": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Orders o,
>   Customer c WHERE o.Route='My Route' c.id=o.Customernum ORDER BY
>   c.StopNum

Comment: Did you forget an 'AND'?

Comment: SELECT o.*,c.* FROM Orders o, Customer c WHERE o.Route='My Route' c.id=o.Customernum ORDER BY c.StopNum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL statement is missing an `AND`:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders o, Customer c WHERE o.Route='My Route' AND 
    c.id=o.Customernum ORDER BY c.StopNum
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed the "and" after looking at it for one hour. What throw me off was the error "near ""c". Thanks.

Comment: I think the `c` it was referring to was the `c.id` part - it was expecting a keyword (such as `AND` or `ORDER BY`) and instead got `c`.